# Can't Add JDBC driver for Oracle in Spring Cloud Data Flow

Tags: oracle, spring-cloud-dataflow

After reading the official documentation on `https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_oracle` its still unclear which pom.xml the dependencies go into and where to put oracle jar file for local spring cloud data-flow server 2.6.0.

Stream Definition

```
   time --trigger.time-unit=SECONDS | httpclient --httpclient.url='******' | jdbc --spring.datas 
   ource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver --spring.datasource.username='******' -- 
   spring.datasource.schema=PARADYMEADMIN --spring.datasource.url='******' -- 
   spring.datasource.password='******'
```

During the deployment this is the error `org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.InvalidConfigurationPropertyValueException: Property spring.datasource.schema with value 'ServletContext resource [/PARADYMEADMIN]' is invalid: The specified resource does not exist.`

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the samples [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/tree/master/custom-dataflow-builds) which help you understand how to build custom SCDF server with the change in JDBC driver for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You need JDBC driver in the classpath. Make sure to provide the following Maven co-ordinates in pom.xml.

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc<groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc8-production</artifactId>
    <version>19.7.0.0</version>
    <type>pom</type>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```